# Laravel update method not working

Tags: php, sql, laravel, foreign-keys, where-clause

I am trying to update my db but it does not work properly.

I build an update method, the problem is that it keeps updating all records with the product_id, whereas it should update each record 
I have for instance 10 records with different values in my db.

If I run the script all records get the first value from the input field.

How do I make it work correctly ?

A little scretch of how my db, looks like this:

```
id      |       product_id       |       short_name      |      input_video
___________________________________________________________________________
 1      |            49          |            de         |       c:\...
 2      |            49          |            en         |       c:\...
 3      |            49          |            tr         |       c:\...
 4      |            49          |            dr         |       c:\...
```

If I run my code (picking de) it looks like this:

```
id      |       product_id       |       short_name      |      input_video
___________________________________________________________________________
 1      |            49          |            de         |       c:\...
 2      |            49          |            de         |       c:\...
 3      |            49          |            de         |       c:\...
 4      |            49          |            de         |       c:\...
```

code:

```
    # save language selection
    $lsCounter = 0;
    $langSelecName = $request->input('language_selection');
    $langSelecFile = $request->file('language_selection');
    if($langSelecName)
    {
        $projectLangPath = $Path . "language";

        foreach($langSelecName as $langSelecNameKey => $langSelecNameValue)
        {
            if($langSelecFile[$lsCounter]['input_vid_lang'] != null)
            {
                $langVidFileName = $langSelecFile[$lsCounter]['input_vid_lang']->getClientOriginalName();

                $languages = new Language();
                $languages['short_name']  = $langSelecNameValue;
                $languages['input_video'] = $projectLangPath . '\\' . $langVidFileName;

                $languages->product()->associate($product);

                $langSelecName = $request->input('language_selection');

                $langData = [
                    'short_name' => $languages['short_name'],
                    'input_video' => $languages['input_video']
                ];

                $intProductID = intval($productID);

                $findLang = $languages->where('product_id', $intProductID);

                $productID = $data['id'];

                if($findLang->update($langData))
                {
                    $langSelecFile[$lsCounter]['input_vid_lang']->move($projectLangPath, $langVidFileName);
                }
            }

            $lsCounter++;
        }
    }
```

My where clause is probably not right, but I am not sure how to fix it.

**Edit**
my Model:

```
<?php

    class Language extends Model
    {

        protected $table = 'products_languages';

        protected $fillable = ['product_id', 'short_name', 'input_video'];

        public function product()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'product_id');
        }

    }
```

**Edit**

View:

```
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" id="language_selection" name="language_selection[]" multiple>
                    @foreach($languages as $languageKey => $languageValue)
                        <option value="<?php echo $languageValue->short_name; ?>"><?php echo $languageValue->name; ?></option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </fieldset>
            @if($type == "edit")
                <input name="id" type="hidden" value="{{ $productId }}">
                @if($languagesCount > 0)
                    @foreach($languages as $languagesKey => $languagesValue)
                        <?php $i = 0 ?>
                            <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file lang-edit">{{ strtoupper($languagesValue->short_name) }}</span>
                        <?php $i++ ?>
                    @endforeach
                @endif
            @endif
```

Comment: Can you provide the content $langSelecName ? Please also add What your Language model / or class? looks like. Why do you hadd short_name and input_video as associative array constraints and not using object operator?

Comment: @Frank Provost I get this output array:1 [▼
  0 => "de"
]

Comment: @FrankProvost I added my model

Comment: It's really hard for me to understand your current code. It seems like you do not really use all the features of laravel you could. This makes it hard to read. Maybe you can describe in a simple way what you actually want to achieve in your code. How does your frontend look like? Why you need a loop through your input data if it only contains one value.

Comment: @FrankProvost I added my view for that specific problem

Comment: you should reduce that code to what matters, better show the final html code here. It does not show how you call your actual route. I cannot see where the language_selection input is. I only see a hidden input and spans. Can you maybe just explain what you want to do ? not generic stuff, just what exactly you try to achieve with your method. Do you want to set a new language for given product id? Do you want to select many languages?

Comment: @FrankProvost added question, currently I click on a language in my select option foreach chosen option I get an input type file for the video input. Later on it saves the data in my db. If I want to update the product(the languages) it does not work. If I pick a language lets say german all product with the id of x change to de, that is my problem

Comment: I think we're getting closer :) - so if you do not want to update every entry with that product id, why do you pass the product id in the view (hidden input) instead of the actual id?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118899/discussion-between-frank-provost-and-john-doe-2).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the order here is a bit messed up:

```
        $intProductID = intval($productID);

        $findLang = $languages->where('product_id', $intProductID);

        $productID = $data['id'];
```

You probably mean to do:

```
        $productID = $data['id'];

        $intProductID = intval($productID);

        $findLang = $languages->where('product_id', $intProductID);
```

Which is the same as:

```
        $findLang = $languages->where('product_id', intval($data['id']));
```

Since I don't see you using these IDs anywhere else.

Comment: You're updating the database rows where product_id = 49, so you're updating all the rows... that's probably not what you want.

Comment: Use the 'id' field instead of 'productId' if that's possible

Answer (score 0):

I reformatted and renamed and reworked a lot. My assumptions are defined in the comments at the very top

```
// $product_id = 1 
// $lang_select_name = ["TR"] => on create it was ["DE", "EN"] and is now updated with TR only
// $lang_select_file = [<fileTR>] => on create it was [<fileDE>,<fileEN>]
// $projectLangPath = '' // whatever your path is

// first of all get the product 
$product = Product::find($product_id);

// list all existing short_names for product id
$existing = $product->languages->lists('short_name');

// tbd: delete every entry that is existing but not in $lang_select_name

// loop through given input of names 
for($i = 0; $i < count($lang_select_name); $i++) 
{
    // check that file is not null => should be done in validation if required
    if($lang_select_file[$i]['input_vid_lang'] != null)
    {
        // get the filename
        $vid_name = $lang_select_file[$i]['input_vid_lang']->getClientOriginalName();

        // first check if the language entry exists already
        $lang = Language::where('product_id', '=', $product_id)->where('short_name', '=', $lang_select_name[$i])->first();

        if(!$lang) {
            // create it 
            $lang = Product->languages()->create([
                "product_id" => $product_id,
                "short_name" => $lang_select_name[$i],
                "input_video" => $projectLangPath . '/' . $vid_name
            ]);
        } else {
            // update
            $lang->input_video = $projectLangPath . '/' . $vid_name;
            $lang->save();
        }
        // move the file
        $lang_select_file[$i]['input_vid_lang']->move($projectLangPath, $vid_name);
    }
}
```

The basic steps are:

- Fetch product with given product id
- Fetch all already existing langages for given product
- Compare input of languages ( short names ) to feteched languages
- tbd : delete every language that is not given in input
- Loop through short names of input

  - foreach short name fetching matching language for given product_id
  - if cannot be found create one, otherwise update existing
- Move the file ( could also check if nothing changed - then do not re-create )